# ¿Cómo realizo el import de los css y js en php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Recientemente, me he topado con un problema al realizar el import de los CSS y JS en mi código.

Esta es la estructura de archivos:

```
docure
|-models
|--css
|---bootstrap.css
|--js
|---bootstrap.js
|--index.php
|--navbar.php
|--main
|---crm
|----index.php
|-views
|--index2.php
```

El código de **`index2.php`**:

```
<?php
include_once "../../models/navbar.php";
include_once "../../models/main/crm/index.php";
```

El código de **`navbar.php`**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>Docure</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../../models/images/favicon.png">
    <link href="../../models/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../models/css/tabla.css">
  <link href="../../models/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../../models/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../../models/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../../models/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../../models/css/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../../models/css/buttons.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <script src="../../models/js/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../models/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="../../models/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../models/js/custom.js"></script>
  <script src="../../models/js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../models/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../models/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../models/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../models/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../models/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../models/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../models/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<?php
session_start();
$idproyecto = $_SESSION['idproyecto'];
$idusuario = $_SESSION['idsessionuser'];
$idperfil = $_SESSION['idperfil'];
?>
<nav class="sb-topnav navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <!-- Navbar Brand-->

    <img src="../../models/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img">
    <a class="navbar-brand ps-3 align-self-center" href="../views/index.php">DOCURE</a>
    <span class="divider"></span>

    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ms-md-0 me-3 me-lg-4">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-light" href="../../views/index.php">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link  text-light dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="bi bi-arrow-left-right"></i> Procesos
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../procesos/index.php">Logistica</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link  text-light dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="bi bi-x-diamond"></i> CRM
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../procesos/index.php">Logistica</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link  text-light dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="bi bi-repeat"></i> Transformación
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="transformacion/index.php">Lotes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link  text-light dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="bi bi-list-task"></i> Producción
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../procesos/index.php">Lotes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item align-self-center">
            <span class="small text-light"><i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i> <?php echo $_SESSION['nombres'] . " " . $_SESSION['apellidos'] ?></span>
            <span class="divider"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item align-self-center">
            <a class="nav-link text-light" href="../../controllers/cerrarSesion.php"><i class="bi bi-box-arrow-right"></i> Salir</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

El código de **`../../models/main/crm/index.php`** es un simple *Hola mundo*.

El problema que tengo es que cuando abro **`|--index.php`** se cargan correctamente los css y js del *nav* que también le hago include, pero cuando abro **`|-index.php`** no se cargan correctamente los css y js.

O sea, uso el mismo *nav* para todas las vistas y me funciona correctamente si empezando desde la raíz del proyecto hay 2 niveles para llegar al css y js, pero si donde hago el include del nav no hay esos niveles, entonces no carga el css y el js, como se puede evidenciar en la captura que adjunto, me toco crear un navbar2.php (los css tienen un nivel menos) para cuando debo incluirlo en otros niveles.

Entonces quisiera pedir ayuda sobre como podría hacer para evitar ese navbar2.php y que me funcione en cualquier nivel. Por ejemplo, si hago el include de la **`navbar.php`** en
**`docure/models/main/crm/estado/`** me siga funcionando el css y js sin tener que crear un **`navbar3.php`** y ajustar los niveles de cada import.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: Captura estructura proyecto]

Comment: No entendí mucho el problema, creo que te has enredado, por ejemplo dices que  `|--index.php` te carga bien y luego dices que no.  Tienes 2 rutas la del servidor y la del cliente. Cuando haces un `include` en el servidor es como si copiaras y pegaras ese código dentro de otro php, esto el cliente no lo sabe ni le interesa. Por tanto, las rutas que están dentro del archivo include deben ser relativas al archivo que realiza el include

Comment: Yusseff, gracias por la observación, ya corregi la publicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has probado haciendo rutas absolutas a los directorios??

A la rápida se me ocurre algo así:

```
<?php
    define('SITE_ROOT', '/'); // root
    define("SLASH", '/'); // Separador
    define("PROYECT_ROOT", SITE_ROOT.'DOCURE'.SLASH); // root de tu proyecto
    echo PROYECT_ROOT;
    // Resultado del echo: /DOCURE/

    define("CSS_DIR", PROYECT_ROOT.'css'.SLASH);
    echo '<br>'.CSS_DIR;
    // Resultado del echo: /DOCURE/css/

    define("JS_DIR", PROYECT_ROOT.'js'.SLASH);
    echo '<br>'.JS_DIR;
    // Resultado del echo: /DOCURE/js/
```

Luego en el HTML hice pruebas así:

```html
<!-- CSS Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo PROYECT_ROOT.'style.css'; ?>">
```

Como resultado, los estilos de **style.css** se cargaron exitosamente y al ver el código fuente, aparece así:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/DOCURE/css/style.css">
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, me funciono ese método, incluso puedo adaptarlo para otras cosas en el proyecto.

Comment: @AndresGallardoMartínez acepta la respuesta entonces. Me alegra que te haya funcionado.