# ¿Por qué no me detecta el CSS con PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, web

Tengo la siguiente estructura de carpetas:

[image: Estructura de carpetas para pagina web]

Y el siguiente código:
[image: Error]

A la hora de abrirlo en Apache me sale que no se encuentra el recurso, ya trate de varias formas incluso usando "" y nada, alguien sabe que tengo que hacer o por que pasa? lo he usado en OndeDrive, USB y local y lo mismo.

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/main.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary" style="background-color: rgb(32,32,32)">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="Nav-colorW" href="#">Asociación</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ventas</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Precios</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Experiencias</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ayuda</a>
    <form class="d-flex" role="search">
      <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<img src="../Resources/ej1.png" alt="">
```

Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
En el navegador eso es lo que me da.

Las carpetas las he creado con permiso 0777 y tampoco me las detecta así como cuando la vuelvo a borrar y a crear no pasa de ahi dice que no encuentra el archivo "main.css" y no es la primera vez que me pasa, la ultima vez tube que volver a crear todo el proyecto en otra ubicacion para que a los dias me volviera a dar el error.

Comment: Saludos, por favor agrega el código como texto y no como captura, para que el problema pueda ser mas visible. ;)

Comment: A propósito podrías agregar el error que comentas que te sale al ejecutarlo??, a simple vista todo parece estar correcto

Comment: Pero ¿por qué daría error en Apache? A lo sumo verías un error 404 en la consola del navegador. Agrega el mensaje de error, como texto y dinos la ruta completa del archivo `.php` que genera el error.

Comment: Ya has verificado el tema de Cache? [Prueba con esto también](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/601172/c%C3%B3mo-realizo-el-import-de-los-css-y-js-en-php/601179#601179)

Comment: Parece que al configurar apache cambiando la ruta de acceso de "C:/Users/ARM/OneDrive/Documents/Asociacion/Pagina web/Layout"
a: "C:/Users/ARM/OneDrive/Documents/Asociacion"
se soluciona el problema. Por que sera?